# I'm running into an error trying to push to Heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku

I'm having an error and I've googled it a lot and nothing seems to work. I've tried **fetch**, **pull**, **push**, **rebase** and many on Stack Overflow. I also recloned the repo to see if that would help but nothing is working.

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Have you initiated using the command "heroku login"? 
Then tried to set the url? Then pulled?
using this command "$git remote set-url heroku <url>"

Comment: So I just tried logging in, set the url to the repo, pulled, pushed (just in case), and then tried pushing to heroku. Same error as above.

Comment: It's saying that heroku has changes that don't exist in your branch. Either pull from that remote or - if you are absolutely confident you don't need the changes on heroku - force push the changes. Beware.

Comment: @osowskit: That lets me start pushing things to Heroku but it opens a new can of worms; something called "whitenoise" is not configured correctly.